# polymorphic relationship with not all columns in common

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

I have the followings tables

```
threads
- id

profile_posts
- id

replies
- id
- repliable_id
- repliable_type
- position
```

- Both **Threads**  needs a model that has **id, body, position**.
- While, **ProfilePosts** needs a model that has **id, body**

The issue here is that if i use a polymorphic relationship, then for all **ProfilePosts** i will have the column **position** which is not used at all.

Is this a reason to use 2 tables instead of a polymorphic relationship. For example, to have

```
threads
 - id

thread_replies
- id
- body
- position

profile_posts
- id

profile_post_replies
- id
- body
```

Comment: Having a table with a column that is unused (`null` value) for some of the records is not uncommon in database designs. If using a single table to store the replies does not pose an issue when fetching/processing/displaying them, then go ahead.

Answer (score 1):

Both approaches are valid.  The downside to the polymorphic approach is that the database cannot (easily) enforce foreign key relationships.  That is, guaranteeing that the type and the id refer to the same table is tricky.  And you might have some entity-specific columns in the table.

Multiple tables is perhaps more common -- and it allows all foreign key relationships to be seen at once.  However, if you want to see all the related entities, then you need to carefully craft the queries.  Multiple `join`s will produce Cartesian products, which is generally not desired.

The shortcomings of both these methods can be handled, but the solutions are not particularly elegant.